# To make it easier to do or to make doing easier

Tags: meaning

> Successive governments have passed modest reforms to make doing business cleanly a little easier.
>
> Successive governments have passed modest reforms to make it a little easier to do business cleanly.

Is there any difference between to make it eaiser to do and to make doing business ? Would it mean the same or different when I say these sentences?

Answer (score 1):

I would say they mean exactly the same. I find the second much clearer, because it is easier to parse.